# Is there another way to provide PDO with the unique column key when using PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE than in the SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am updating an old internal library to use PHP's PDO extension. In the old code, there's a function where the first parameter was a line of SQL and then the second parameter was an optional column to use as the key. I need to keep this same function signature so I don't break any code.

I'd like to use PDO's `FETCH_UNIQUE` fetch mode, but it would require me to parse every line of SQL that is passed in and add the key column to the beginning of the select. I'm worried that there are edge cases that I wouldn't think of that would break the call.

Is there another way in PDO to designate which column to use as the key when using PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE other than to add it directly to the column list in the SQL call?

**Edit:**

Here's some example code and more details:

```
$db = new Database();
$query = "first_name, last_name, contacts_id from contacts where first_name='George'";
$uniqueKeyField = "contacts_id";
$contact = $db->getRows($query, $uniqueKeyField);
```

Which would yield:

```
array (
    [34] => array (
        "first_name" => "George",
        "last_name" => "Smith",
    ),
    [452] => array (
        "first_name" => "George",
        "last_name" => "Johnson",
    )
)
```

The problem is, I cannot always guarantee that the unique keyField will be first in the list like PDO requires because that was not a requirement of our API before.

After going through the manual, my guess is this is not possible to do with `PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE` and we will either have to use `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` and loop through the results like we used to and build our own array or change every call to the above function in existing code to rearrange the fields so the unique keyfield is first. I was hoping someone knew of a way you could just pass the unique keyfield as an argument somewhere, but my guess is PDO faces the same problem we do - they have to have the keyfield in the query somewhere to pull out and put as the id in the returned array and they don't want to have to try to parse and add it to existing queries, thus the requirement to have it as the first field.

Comment: Could you add some example code from the old library used and what you're trying to match it up with now? That way it would probably help (others) to see what can be done. If nobody answered/commented earlier, then that would probably be the reason why. Going through the manual may also yield results if you haven't gone through it already http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I've added some more details. After some more research, I don't think it's possible to do what I was hoping to do and we'll either just have to adjust every place we use the API in our code or write our own solution without using PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE. If anyone knows of another solution, please provide an answer.